# How to get data from a table with a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to get the data from a table into an array, and I want to use a foreach loop not a while for speed issues.

I tried using

```
function getRowsAssoc()
{
    $ret = array();
    while (($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if (count($temp) > 0)
        {
            $ret[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if (count($ret) > 0)
    {
        return $ret;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

However this results in to.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [MySKU] => BB1-3500-48 [UPC] => 721343100171 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [MySKU] => BC7-3501-19 [UPC] => 721343103516 )
    [2] => Array ( [MySKU] => BC7-3501-95 [UPC] => 721343103523 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [MySKU] => BB1-3502-12 [UPC] => 721343114000 )
    [4] => Array ( [MySKU] => bc7-2370-03 [UPC] => 721343121602 )
)
```

the problem with this is that instead of returning an Assoc array it is adding a numbered array in top of it so now I cannot get the data from the item codes.

I would like to get like this

```
Array (
         [MySKU] => BB1-3500-48 [UPC] => 721343100171 
         [MySKU] => BC7-3501-19 [UPC] => 721343103516 
        [MySKU] => BC7-3501-95 [UPC] => 721343103523  
        [MySKU] => BB1-3502-12 [UPC] => 721343114000 
        [MySKU] => bc7-2370-03 [UPC] => 721343121602 
    )
```

Comment: Note: use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql (Deprecated as of 5.5).

Comment: "for speed issues" ... I don't think there's any speed difference between foreach and while or for, at least a human noticeable speed issue

Comment: `foreach` is used to iterate over existing arrays. In this case, you are building the array with `while`. You cannot replace it with `foreach` because there is no array you could use it on.

Comment: What structure of the result assoc array do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the key:

```
function getRowsAssoc()
{
    $ret = array();
    while (($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if (count($temp) > 0)
        {
            $ret[$temp["MySKU"]] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if (count($ret) > 0)
    {
        return $ret;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know, how the structure of the result array should look.

For a structure like

```
Array
(
    [MySKU-x] => UPC-x
    [MySKU-y] => UPC-y
    [MySKU-z] => UPC-z
)
```

you can use this:

```
function getRowsAssoc()
{
    $return = array();
    while (($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) !== false)
    {
        if (count($temp) > 0)
        {
            $return[$temp['MySKU']] = $temp['UPC'];
        }
    }
    if (count($return) > 0)
    {
        return $return;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```